# Playing Flash video on part of a page - iframe versus DIV and Include in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, include

I wanted to use DIV and Include in my original page and play an FLV.
I decided to use INCLUDE and reference "videoplayer.html" to play the file, but it wouldn't work. Note: the player uses the MIT Opensource SWFObject v2.2 file, which I had in my header called "lessonheader.php" .

So, this DOES NOT work (just has a blank DIV area):
From my "lessonheader.php" file

```
<head>...
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
... </head>
...
```

From my main page:

```
    include("includes/lessonheader.php");
...
elseif ($answertype == "vid") {
        include '.\videos\videoplayer.html';
        echo '<p>Click next to proceed, or watch the video again.</p>
```

**While if I use a simple iframe, it does:**

```
elseif ($answertype == "vid") {
    echo '<iframe src=".\videos\videoplayer.html"></iframe>';
    echo '<p>Click next to proceed, or watch the video again.</p>
```

For reference, here is the videoplayer.html (note script put at top has no effect on the include not working or the iframe working - just testing it out):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="wb_FlashVideoPlayer1" style="margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;left:10px;top:10px;width:640px;height:480px;text-align:left;z-index:5;">
<p>This is before the player </p>
    <div id="FlashVideoPlayer1"></div>
This is after the player
<script type="text/javascript">
   var flashvars = {};
   var params = {};
   flashvars.videoPath = "addition1.f4v";
...
   params.salign = "tl";
   swfobject.embedSWF("wb.videoplayer.swf", "FlashVideoPlayer1", "640", "480", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params);
</script>
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Forward slashes...

(assuming its Linux)

Comment: You use forward slashes (which apparently works) on lessonheader which tells me otherwise.

Comment: Also, are the .f4v, .swf files in videos directory? in which case you need to modify flashvars.videoPath etc

Comment: sorry... forgot to say running Apache on win server.

Answer (score 0):

I got to the problem. It had to do with where I had the files "swfobject.js", and "wb.videoplayer.swf" relative to the PHP pages in question. I had them in the an "includes" folder, and I thought I had specified that directory.

Thanks all!